# Rounding for months elapsed isn't consistent between creation and migration

Tags: bug, migrated-questions, time

Look at the following question's [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57900591/timeline):

- asked 2019-09-11 23:40:37Z
- migrated 2019-09-12 06:04:11Z

Yet, at of today November 30th 2019, [I can see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57900591/avaje-ebean-failed-at-class-not-enhanced):

- asked 2 months ago
- migrated 3 months ago

[image]

So the display incorrectly states that it was migrated before being asked. It seems that the rounding calculation doesn't follow the same logic in both places.